# Send data to server an open new ASP page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In controller I have method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DailyOverview(int year, int month, int day)
{
    DailyOverviewModel stat = GetDailyData(new DateTime(year, month, day));
    return View(stat);
}
```

Is it possible to call this method using jQuery and pass the year, month and day parameters in a way that controller will then send data to open the new view with stat data?

Comment: jquery (ajax) calls stay on the same page so it wont _open a new view_. You can either do a standard form submit and redirect, or update the DOM of the existing page with the partial view returned by you POST method.

Comment: Can somebody please prepare a sample code. Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, and you have not indicated what you actually want to do - do you want to redirect to another view (in which case use a standard submit) or doo you want to update the existing page (in which case you need to use ajax (e.g jquery `.get()` or `.load()` methods)